# Weird pattern in background

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

So, I have a weird issue with my PC lately. When I boot my PC, my background is not there, but a weird greyish background appears with a pattern in it (see image 1). However, it shows a very small bit in the top left corner of my original background.

[image]
**Image 1: Pattern in the background.**
Funny thing is, when I enter the Personalization settings in windows 10, It automatically sets the correct background and I do not have this issue anymore (see image). However, when I start playing a game (does not matter which one) the pattern is back again.

How do I fix this? This did not happen shortly after a driver update from my AMD GPU. Nevertheless, I did tried to downgrade my driver version. This didn't solve it sadly.

[image]

**Image 2: Overview of the desktop. Notice how the top left corner up to the center is partly showing the background image.**
[image]

**Image 3: Before I click "Personalize setttingc etc" the background is still the same.**
[image]

**Image 4: As soon as the settings are opened, the correct background is displayed.**